# MySQL Daemon failed to start on centos

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL 5.7 in my CentOS and tried to start the service but that gives this error.

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

`mysqld.log` contains

```
2016-05-19T06:49:42.595371Z mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases fr                                             om /var/lib/mysql
2016-05-19T06:49:42.726232Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is                                              deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see doc                                             umentation for more details).
2016-05-19T06:49:42.726437Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.12) starting a                                             s process 6511 ...
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729712Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729734Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic                                              builtins
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729740Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729746Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is                                              used for memory barrier
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729752Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729759Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-05-19T06:49:42.729980Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2016-05-19T06:49:42.730080Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-05-19T06:49:42.736659Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total siz                                             e = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2016-05-19T06:49:42.744976Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer                                              pool
2016-05-19T06:49:42.746579Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is aut                                             horized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpri                                             ority().
2016-05-19T06:49:42.758283Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Ba                                             rracuda.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.773498Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temp                                             orary tables
2016-05-19T06:49:42.773597Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12                                              MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2016-05-19T06:49:42.868794Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.869616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found.                                              96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.869630Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are                                              active.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.870091Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-05-19T06:49:42.920263Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.12 started; log sequence number                                              47501023
2016-05-19T06:49:42.920461Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.920730Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be                                              transactional.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921136Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Tabl                                             e 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921212Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the foll                                             owing SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and priva                                             te key
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921371Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port:                                              3306
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921426Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921438Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921446Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921635Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/li                                             b/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-05-19T06:49:42.921792Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 16                                             0519 12:19:42
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923348Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant t                                             ables

2016-05-19T06:49:42.923623Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged.                                              Please run mysql_upgrade.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923679Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-05-19T06:49:42.923691Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923731Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923741Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923746Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923750Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923754Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923815Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923826Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACE                                             S'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923829Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_CO                                             LS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923833Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923841Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923844Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923848Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923851Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS                                             '
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923858Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE                                             '
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923862Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE                                             '
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923865Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923870Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELET                                             ED'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923873Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923877Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STO                                             PWORD'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923880Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923883Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INF                                             O'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923887Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_ST                                             ATS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923890Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LR                                             U'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923893Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923897Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_                                             RESET'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923900Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923903Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923907Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923910Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923913Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923917Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923920Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923923Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923927Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-05-19T06:49:42.923971Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-05-19T06:49:42.924055Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-05-19T06:49:43.024521Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/                                             mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2016-05-19T06:49:43.024711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 16                                             0519 12:19:43
2016-05-19T06:49:44.541254Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence nu                                             mber 47501042
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data f                                             ile: "ibtmp1"
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542655Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542666Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542671Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542687Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542702Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password                                             '
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542816Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-05-19T06:49:44.542996Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2016-05-19T06:49:44.549488Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mys                                             qld.pid ended
```

`df -hT` gives :

```
Filesystem                    Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root ext4   6.7G  5.4G  1.2G  83% /
tmpfs                         tmpfs  435M   68K  435M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                     ext4   485M   40M  420M   9% /boot
```

Comment: Try finding out where the error log is with : 'grep log /etc/mysql/my.cnf'. Then look into the error log file. It will tell you what happened.

Comment: Hi, Can you give us more information about which version of CentOS you are using ? Are you using SysInit Scripts ? Systemd ? to manage you're services ?

Comment: Is it possible that you should init it as superuser?

Comment: `/var/log/mysqld.log` is your friend to check.

Comment: @gerhardd. I'm getting this as error,                                                2016-05-18T13:11:06.629712Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 0, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2016-05-18T13:11:06.629729Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'

Comment: rather than extending conversation here, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/284087/edit) your question. and post what error your getting. post output of `/var/log/mysqld.log` and `df -hT`

Comment: Why don't we see the error number in your log?  Are you running out of disk space as it mentions?  Check `df`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier no, my disk is not full. It has more space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### MySQL's log is telling you the problem, quite clearly.

> I installed MySQL 5.7 in my CentOS […]
>
> ```
> 2016-05-19T06:49:42.923623Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged. Please run mysql_upgrade.
> 2016-05-19T06:49:42.923679Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> ```

You did not install MySQL.  You *upgraded an existing* MySQL installation, without upgrading the database schemata to what version 5.7 expects.

And like these people …

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725665/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906991/

… you find that MySQL won't like your databases and will refuse to start with them until after you have upgraded them to the new schemata.

[Vitalijus Ryzakovas says](http://www.linuxhow.tk/fatal-error-mysql-user-table-is-damaged-please-run-mysql_upgrade/) to just reinstall the entire database with the installation utility, losing all prior data.

[Reindl Harald says](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/231430) to be *careful about CentOS repositories*.  Xe echoes Oracle's own advice to *upgrade only one release level at a time*.

The person whose repository M. Harald was talking about, [Remi Collet, says](http://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=3369) to downgrade to the old version of MySQL once more, dump the entire database set to file, upgrade once again, and restore from the dump.

Oracle describes both the upgrade and the dump-restore methods in the doco, the former being an *in-place upgrade* and the latter being a *logical upgrade*.

### Further reading

- [Upgrading MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html).  MySQL Reference manual.  5.7.  Oracle corporation.
- [`mysql_upgrade`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html).  MySQL Reference manual.  5.7.  Oracle corporation.
- [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html).  MySQL Reference manual.  5.7.  Oracle corporation.

Answer (score 0):

> no space left on the device

could also mean that the partition is out of inodes. Use `df -i` to check inode usage.

It's unusual to run out of inodes, so it's possible you have some directory full of small or zero-length files somewhere that you're not aware of. Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to find this sort of thing. Running `find / -xdev` would print the name of every file and directory on the partition. You might be able to spot some suspicious directory full of empty files.

I had tried once when I had over millions of inodes used.

```
find . -type f -name sess_* -delete
```

**Update**

try this steps :

```
mysqld_safe –skip-grant-tables –user=root &
mysql_fix_privilege_tables
pkill mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: tried `df -i`  `Filesystem                    Type  Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on  /dev/mapper/vg_livecd-lv_root ext4    432K  116K  317K   27%  /  tmpfs                         tmpfs   109K     2  109K    1%  /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                     ext4    126K    41  125K    1%  /boot`

Comment: @user2649815 please make sure `mysqld` daemon is running by `service mysqld status`

Comment: that is where I have issue. I'm not able to start it and it is in stopped state.

Comment: @user2649815 try update one

Answer (score -1):

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql
chkconfig --level 345 mysql on
service mysqld start
```

Comment: This is just a list of commands, someone who asks for help might know or might not know what they mean. In my opinion some explanations would be nice.